# AJAX: People interacting on a page in real time without a database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Background**

I am trying to design an interactive classroom type of environment. The room has different slides, a chat box and some other basic features.

**My understanding**

A sure way to update a page in real time for all users is for one person to persist a change via ajax to a database, then all the other users poll the server at a timed interval (one second) to check for changes... if there are their view gets updated.

[image]

**My code**

Each room has a unique URL... http://www.example.com/room/ajc73

Users slide through the clides using this code:

```js
showCard();

function showCard() {
  $('#card-' + (cardId)).show();
}

$('#nextCard').click(function() {
  nextCard();
});

$('#previousCard').click(function() {
  previousCard();
});

function nextCard() {
  if ($('#card-' + (cardId + 1)).length != 0) { // if there is a next card
    $('#card-' + (cardId)).hide(); // hide current card
    cardId++; // increment the card id
    $('#card-' + (cardId)).show(); // and show the next card
    location.hash = cardId;
  }
}


function previousCard() {
  if (cardId != 1) { // if we are not at the first card
    $('#card-' + (cardId)).hide(); // hide the current card
    cardId--; // decrement the card id
    $('#card-' + (cardId)).show(); // and show the previous card
    location.hash = cardId;
  }
}
```

**My question**

Am I required to persist data from *user1* to the database in order for it to be called and displayed to *user2* or is there a way to cut out the database part and push changes directly to the browser?

Comment: You have to store the data server-side somewhere, be it a database or any other type of storage (e.g. files)

Comment: better use [php websocket](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket) its connect client to client without database

Comment: @prasad, thanks... that's the type of thing I was trying to avoid for fear that it would be more opportunity for me to make a mistake/get hacked... time to learn something new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for websockets. that will be a better option. since its real-time and just a simpler logic will help you achieve the result.
If you are not sure that whether you will be able to use websockets(like if you are using shared hosting and your provider doesn't allow this or any other reason) you can go for various services like pusher(easier to understand) that will help to do your job  but with some cost.

Comment: So I decided on pusher (free deal is amazing actually), this will be perfect for now, so unbelievably easy to set up!

Comment: ask me for help. whenever needed.  I am happy that I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sockets and just broadcast any input to every client.

Of course, the same can be done with ajax and a rest api but it'll be harder, i'll use pseudocode:

```
clients = {};

fn newclient() {
  clients[client_id] = {
    pool: [];
    ....
  }
}

fn onNewMessage(newmessage) {
  forEach(client, fn(c) {
    c.pool.push(newmessage);
  })
}

fn clientRequestNews() {
  response = clients[client].pool;
  clients[client].pool.length = 0;
  return response;
}
```

the point here is, in server memory there would be a entry for each client, each of them has a pool, when a new message is sent to the server, it's pushed to every client's pool.
When a client ask's for news, the server will return the clients pool, after that, it'll clean the pool of that client.

With this you dont need persistence.

Answer (score 1):

Use web sockets. [Please see here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/start-using-html5-websockets-today--net-13270)

Answer (score 1):

You need websockets, a datastructure server and a pub/serve model with events:
[A hint](https://gist.github.com/sebastiaanluca/c80db73d720c3307b4867e6af86369ef)